# How to click a button and then navigate to a specific folder?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

How can I open the windows explorer at a specific folder/path (e.g. C:\Windows) from code? (e.g. using a button_click event)

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do?  Open a file? Then you should take a look at OpenFileDialog.

Comment: I added a new item in right-click menu, where I customize some items of the folders where I always visit. so I dont need to click the folder one by one. I could just click one time and then navigate to that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start a process (in your case open a path in explorer) just use the following code:

```
Process.Start(@"c:\windows\");
```

It's located in the System Diagnostic namespace:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```